# Remove Specific HTML Tags from String with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string with some HTML in it.  Example...

```
<tr id="problem_header">
  <td width="50%">Unit 5, Lesson 2: Ordering Decimals</td>
  <td width="50%">Notes</span></td>
</tr>
<tr id="border_row">
  <td class="border_cell" id="border_cell">----</td>
  <td class="border_cell" id="border_cell">----</td>
</tr>

<tr class="problem_display_row">
  <td valign="middle" class="problem_display" id="problem_display">
    Place the following numbers in order from least to greatest. 
    <br><br>
    0.0032, &nbsp;0.0016, &nbsp;0.0097, &nbsp;0.0075, &nbsp;0.0049
  </td>
  <td valign="middle" class="notes_display" id="notes_display">
  </td>
</tr>

<tr class="problem_display_work">
  <td valign="middle" class="problem_display" id="problem_display">
    <span class="emphasis">0.0016, &nbsp;0.0032, &nbsp;0.0049, &nbsp;0.0075, &nbsp;0.0097</span>
  </td>
  <td valign="middle" class="notes_display" id="notes_display">
  Starting with the highest place value, compare each corresponding place value on each number.  Highest number wins!  If there's a tie, move on to the next place value and keep going until you have a winner.
  </td>
```

Using javascript, can I take out some of the `<tr>`'s by their ID?  Like, get rid of `<tr id="problem_header">` for example, but leave the other `<tr>`'s??

Answer (score 0):

```
var element = document.getElementById("problem_header");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Comment: Right now the string that has the HTML in it is called "data".  HOw would your solution be applied to this situation?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you provide some code so I know what the DOM looks like?

Comment: `data` is the javascript variable that has the string of HTML.  How would your solution be applied to that situation?  So, it's like `data = '<tr id="problem_header">.....'`

Comment: My solution just uses javascript to first get the element by id, then call the parent node (because you can only remove elements from the parent node), then deletes the selected element. I don't see why you would set the HTML code as a string to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in string format would be hard (probably could with regex, but really hard), but jquery could handle this...

```
var x = $(YOURSTRING)
//remove values from x with regular jquery calls
return x.html()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as the HTML is in string format I guess it is better to execute it first i.e. display all the `tr` along with the `id="problem_header"` and once the tr are loaded remove the one with `id="problem_header"`

You can remove the id as,

```
var element = document.getElementById("problem_header");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Make sure to execute the above script after you have written the script to display all the tr elements.